# Minima of piecewise functions.

Tags: calculus

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}  (x-a)^3 & ,x>a\\
             0  & ,|x| \leq a \\
             (x+a)^3 &,x< -a  \end{cases}$$

I think the third derivative doesn't exist at $x= \pm a$  and higher derivative test doesn't apply for the critical points,  so by using epsilon definition, I concluded the function has a minimum for $a \neq 0$. But the answers say it has no minimum and I am unable to figure out why.  Please help

Comment: It is not clear how your function is defined. Try MathJax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have attached the picture of the function.

While the function has local minimum, $(-a, a]$ are indeed local minimum. It is clear that there is no global minimum as $\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) = -\infty$. Your book might be referring to global minimum does not exist.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The function goes to negative infinity as x goes to negative infinity.  So, no global minimum.

As for local minima, everything in (-a,a] is a local minimum.

Also, all derivatives do exist.

Comment: For x = a the LHD = 0 whereas the RHD =  6. So the derivative doesn't exist at the point x = a , similar argument holds for x = -a.